# Broken SilverStripe Template

Tags: php, silverstripe

For some reason, after doing a ?flush=all, a certain page type is not able to locate it's default template. I figure out that it's not loading it's template file after appending showtemplate=1 to the URL. The dumped raw template shows nothing for the default template.

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/uMLefAsP

I wish someone could point me to the right direction here, for I have no idea where to start debugging.

Thanks, Jan.

Comment: What's the name of the missing template? Which folder is it in?

Comment: It's in the theme folder, the same where all of the templates are. All of the other templates are currently working just fine, just this specific file of which I have a problem.

You can see it live here:
Working -> [link](http://ns1.dmsf.edu.ph/beta/index.php/) 
Working ->[link](http://ns1.dmsf.edu.ph/beta/index.php/academic) 
Not working ->[link](http://ns1.dmsf.edu.ph/beta/index.php/community)

Comment: I forgot, the name of the template is: CommunityExtensionPage.ss

Comment: I guess you have the right theme enabled :) .. is this a "main" template or under Layout or Include? Might be usefull to see some code and maybe a folder tree...

Comment: this is a main template for I have declared a separate page type for this. For the site tree, kindly refer to this [link](http://prntscr.com/2amy62)

Comment: Since there is a second one in Layout, you have a $Layout call in your main template? Though I don't see the need? Does your controller overrides the template at some point? Can you link your templates code and the Controller and any parent classe?

Comment: Theme/Layout/CommunityExtensionPage.ss [link](http://pastebin.com/EfbYmnTg)

Theme/CommunityExtension.ss [link](http://pastebin.com/9yzi8YaE)

Controller/CommunityExtension.php
[link](http://pastebin.com/6V7MkUd9)

I think the other includes are irrelevant for they work on the other templates too. But let me know if you need them.

Comment: Some weird things about your folder strusture... Why are you templates straight into the theme folder. It should be `themes/MyTheme/templates` and `themes/MyTheme/templates/Layout`. Also why is `$Layout` commented out, since the rest of your template is under Layout, you'll need this uncommented.....

Comment: My bad, the actual template location is: themes/mytheme/templates. And also, the $Layout was not commented. I was just testing for another way to display the layout page from the controller, but still isn't working. Anyways,
my templates were in a path settings as you mention, i just included  a "path" in the pastebin so you might not get confused with the Layout template and the main template.

Comment: Looked again at your ?showtemplate output, and your templates are found. Also, if the actually template was not found it would use the next best thing (Page) since it extends Page. The templates are also found when visiting /academic so I'm just thinking the problem is somewhere else. Are /academic and /community the same class? Any linked DataObject that would create errors? Do you get any errors? Anything in the SS log or PHP log?

Comment: No errors for me. And I created a separate class for Academic and Community because both pages contain different types of information in it. Can you check again for: [http://ns1.dmsf.edu.ph/beta/index.php/community?showtemplate=1&debug=1&isDev=1](http://ns1.dmsf.edu.ph/beta/index.php/community?showtemplate=1&debug=1&isDev=1)
And there are no DataObjects I know of that I used or created for these templates. Nothing unusual too in the PHP log. I'm not quite sure about the SS log though, because I don't know where I could ifnd that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, and I have to ask: Is there actually a PageType called "CommunityExtensionPage"? PageTypes need to be named the same as the required template, for the template to be picked-up automatically.

You seem to have two template files "CommunityExtensionPage.ss". One at "templates/CommunityExtensionPage.ss" and one at "templates/Layout/CommunityExtensionPage.ss"

It would be useful to see the contents of both files. SilverStripe will look for "CommunityExtensionPage.ss" in the top-level of the "templates" dir before looking in "templates/Layout".

If "templates/CommunityExtensionPage.ss" is found, it will also try and look for "templates/Layout/CommunityExtensionPage.ss" and render this into the $Layout template variable. Otherwise, it'll use the default "templates/Page.ss" and request "templates/Layout/CommunityExtensionPage.ss"

Does your "templates/CommunityExtensionPage.ss" template contain a reference to $Layout? If not, then the contents of "templates/Layout/CommunityExtensionPage.ss" will not be rendered.